# Google fit activity not giving any 'Still' type of activity from Android device

Tags: android, google-fit

For the past few days, around 20th Jan onwards for a lot of user we are not getting any ‘Still’ from Google fit activity type. We are using Google-fit data since more than 2 years but have never experienced something like this where users are not getting any sedentary data.

It is practically impossible for a user to not have any sedentary data for over 6 days
Please find below the example response of one of such user:

```
2021-02-02 12:37:15.032 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-25T18:30:00.000Z End time: 2021-01-25T18:45:04.574Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.033 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-25T18:45:04.574Z End time: 2021-01-25T18:52:57.606Z Activity type: in_vehicle
2021-02-02 12:37:15.034 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-25T18:52:57.606Z End time: 2021-01-26T04:24:23.232Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.035 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T04:24:23.232Z End time: 2021-01-26T04:25:08.984Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.035 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T04:25:08.984Z End time: 2021-01-26T04:34:56.038Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.036 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T04:34:56.038Z End time: 2021-01-26T04:36:00.800Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.037 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T04:36:00.800Z End time: 2021-01-26T05:10:15.556Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.038 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T05:10:15.556Z End time: 2021-01-26T05:11:24.000Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.039 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T05:11:24.000Z End time: 2021-01-26T05:29:20.000Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.039 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T05:29:20.000Z End time: 2021-01-26T06:14:52.810Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.040 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T06:14:52.810Z End time: 2021-01-26T06:16:22.733Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.041 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T06:16:22.733Z End time: 2021-01-26T06:26:35.716Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.041 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T06:26:35.716Z End time: 2021-01-26T06:27:05.873Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.042 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T06:27:05.873Z End time: 2021-01-26T06:38:15.771Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.042 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T06:38:15.771Z End time: 2021-01-26T06:41:47.331Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.044 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T06:41:47.331Z End time: 2021-01-26T14:37:18.117Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.044 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T14:37:18.117Z End time: 2021-01-26T14:38:39.616Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.045 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T14:38:39.616Z End time: 2021-01-26T17:15:52.995Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.048 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T17:15:52.995Z End time: 2021-01-26T17:46:44.032Z Activity type: in_vehicle
2021-02-02 12:37:15.050 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T17:46:44.032Z End time: 2021-01-26T17:58:36.426Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.052 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T17:58:36.426Z End time: 2021-01-26T18:05:23.438Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.053 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T18:05:23.438Z End time: 2021-01-26T18:07:03.855Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.054 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T18:07:03.855Z End time: 2021-01-26T18:27:35.554Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.055 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T18:27:35.554Z End time: 2021-01-26T18:49:41.142Z Activity type: in_vehicle
2021-02-02 12:37:15.056 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-26T18:49:41.142Z End time: 2021-01-27T03:55:25.886Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.056 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-27T03:55:25.886Z End time: 2021-01-27T03:59:12.347Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.057 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-27T03:59:12.347Z End time: 2021-01-27T05:49:11.708Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.057 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-27T05:49:11.708Z End time: 2021-01-27T05:49:59.499Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.058 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-27T05:49:59.499Z End time: 2021-01-27T05:55:05.887Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.059 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-27T05:55:05.887Z End time: 2021-01-27T06:01:37.012Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.059 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-27T06:01:37.012Z End time: 2021-01-27T07:26:11.983Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.060 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-27T07:26:11.983Z End time: 2021-01-27T07:27:12.142Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.060 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-27T07:27:12.142Z End time: 2021-01-28T03:47:09.014Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.062 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-28T03:47:09.014Z End time: 2021-01-28T03:47:26.080Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.062 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-28T03:47:26.080Z End time: 2021-01-28T03:47:56.293Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.064 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-28T03:47:56.293Z End time: 2021-01-28T03:47:58.605Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.065 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-28T03:47:58.605Z End time: 2021-01-28T04:22:46.000Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.065 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-28T04:22:46.000Z End time: 2021-01-28T04:48:22.000Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.066 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-28T04:48:22.000Z End time: 2021-01-28T06:18:04.472Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.066 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-28T06:18:04.472Z End time: 2021-01-28T06:20:22.356Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.067 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-28T06:20:22.356Z End time: 2021-01-28T15:00:48.326Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.067 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-28T15:00:48.326Z End time: 2021-01-28T15:05:02.681Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.068 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-28T15:05:02.681Z End time: 2021-01-28T15:10:20.961Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.068 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-28T15:10:20.961Z End time: 2021-01-28T15:11:21.075Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.069 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-28T15:11:21.075Z End time: 2021-01-28T15:13:58.587Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.069 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-28T15:13:58.587Z End time: 2021-01-28T15:14:58.933Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.070 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-28T15:14:58.933Z End time: 2021-01-28T15:29:26.784Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.070 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-28T15:29:26.784Z End time: 2021-01-28T15:29:51.821Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.071 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-28T15:29:51.821Z End time: 2021-01-28T17:25:47.721Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.071 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-28T17:25:47.721Z End time: 2021-01-28T17:26:47.763Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.072 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-28T17:26:47.763Z End time: 2021-01-29T04:07:40.102Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.072 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-29T04:07:40.102Z End time: 2021-01-29T04:07:45.153Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.072 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-29T04:07:45.153Z End time: 2021-01-29T04:08:11.656Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.073 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-29T04:08:11.656Z End time: 2021-01-29T04:27:22.343Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.073 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-29T04:27:22.343Z End time: 2021-01-29T04:34:01.204Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.074 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-29T04:34:01.204Z End time: 2021-01-29T05:51:29.455Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.074 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-29T05:51:29.455Z End time: 2021-01-29T05:51:43.990Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.074 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-29T05:51:43.990Z End time: 2021-01-29T05:53:31.023Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.075 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-29T05:53:31.023Z End time: 2021-01-29T05:57:06.370Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.075 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-29T05:57:06.370Z End time: 2021-01-29T05:58:37.532Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.075 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-29T05:58:37.532Z End time: 2021-01-30T15:04:44.433Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.076 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-30T15:04:44.433Z End time: 2021-01-30T15:41:06.437Z Activity type: in_vehicle
2021-02-02 12:37:15.076 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-30T15:41:06.437Z End time: 2021-01-31T04:57:01.548Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.076 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-31T04:57:01.548Z End time: 2021-01-31T04:57:18.558Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.077 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-31T04:57:18.558Z End time: 2021-01-31T05:07:00.396Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.077 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-31T05:07:00.396Z End time: 2021-01-31T05:10:41.615Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.078 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-31T05:10:41.615Z End time: 2021-01-31T05:11:02.171Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.078 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-31T05:11:02.171Z End time: 2021-01-31T05:19:35.547Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.079 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-31T05:19:35.547Z End time: 2021-01-31T07:19:32.992Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.079 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-31T07:19:32.992Z End time: 2021-01-31T07:26:56.632Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.080 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-31T07:26:56.632Z End time: 2021-01-31T09:06:02.892Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.080 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-31T09:06:02.892Z End time: 2021-01-31T09:07:03.209Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.080 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-31T09:07:03.209Z End time: 2021-01-31T13:09:22.993Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.081 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-31T13:09:22.993Z End time: 2021-01-31T13:11:41.335Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.081 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-31T13:11:41.335Z End time: 2021-01-31T13:33:52.094Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.081 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-31T13:33:52.094Z End time: 2021-01-31T13:35:30.748Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.082 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-31T13:35:30.748Z End time: 2021-01-31T14:54:47.722Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.082 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-31T14:54:47.722Z End time: 2021-01-31T14:56:48.434Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.082 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-31T14:56:48.434Z End time: 2021-01-31T14:58:51.241Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.083 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-31T14:58:51.241Z End time: 2021-01-31T15:02:03.482Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.083 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-31T15:02:03.482Z End time: 2021-01-31T15:02:41.350Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.083 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-31T15:02:41.350Z End time: 2021-01-31T15:08:05.586Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.084 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-01-31T15:08:05.586Z End time: 2021-02-01T05:00:43.122Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.084 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-01T05:00:43.122Z End time: 2021-02-01T05:00:52.066Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.084 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-01T05:00:52.066Z End time: 2021-02-01T05:02:00.056Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.085 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-01T05:02:00.056Z End time: 2021-02-01T05:53:54.530Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.085 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-01T05:53:54.530Z End time: 2021-02-01T05:58:11.088Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.086 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-01T05:58:11.088Z End time: 2021-02-01T16:18:52.340Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.086 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-01T16:18:52.340Z End time: 2021-02-01T16:19:14.479Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.086 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-01T16:19:14.479Z End time: 2021-02-01T16:34:27.643Z Activity type: in_vehicle
2021-02-02 12:37:15.086 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-01T16:34:27.643Z End time: 2021-02-01T16:35:48.037Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.087 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-01T16:35:48.037Z End time: 2021-02-01T16:35:50.103Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.087 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-01T16:35:50.103Z End time: 2021-02-01T16:52:21.220Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.087 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-01T16:52:21.220Z End time: 2021-02-01T16:54:27.078Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.088 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-01T16:54:27.078Z End time: 2021-02-01T19:13:43.116Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.088 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-01T19:13:43.116Z End time: 2021-02-01T19:14:00.250Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.088 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-01T19:14:00.250Z End time: 2021-02-01T19:15:31.338Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.089 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-01T19:15:31.338Z End time: 2021-02-01T19:30:38.259Z Activity type: in_vehicle
2021-02-02 12:37:15.089 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-01T19:30:38.259Z End time: 2021-02-02T04:32:06.104Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.089 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-02T04:32:06.104Z End time: 2021-02-02T04:32:27.603Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.090 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-02T04:32:27.603Z End time: 2021-02-02T04:33:33.243Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.090 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-02T04:33:33.243Z End time: 2021-02-02T04:34:17.985Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.090 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-02T04:34:17.985Z End time: 2021-02-02T04:34:58.839Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.090 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-02T04:34:58.839Z End time: 2021-02-02T04:35:41.992Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.091 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-02T04:35:41.992Z End time: 2021-02-02T04:41:11.626Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.091 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-02T04:41:11.626Z End time: 2021-02-02T04:41:14.329Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.091 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-02T04:41:14.329Z End time: 2021-02-02T04:44:03.081Z Activity type: unknown
2021-02-02 12:37:15.092 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-02T04:44:03.081Z End time: 2021-02-02T04:45:43.847Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.092 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-02T04:45:43.847Z End time: 2021-02-02T04:45:54.094Z Activity type: walking
2021-02-02 12:37:15.092 25537-25537/com.aktivolabs.sample E/FitActivityApiWrapper: Start time: 2021-02-02T04:45:54.094Z End time: 2021-02-02T07:07:14.822Z Activity type: unknown
```

It is observed that frequency of ‘Unknown’ has increased during this period. Please suggest what needs to be done about this.

Answer (score 0):

We did indeed stop persisting `STILL` explicitly, given it seems equivalent to no data.